# Retornar a página anterior depois de fazer login

Tags: javascript, node.js

Montei um site no qual o usuário loga colocando qualquer Login e Senha e armazenando no LocalStorage.
Qual parte do site que ele tentar acessar, sempre redireciona para a página do Login se ele não tiver logado pelo menos 1 vez. (Exemplo: se ele tentar acessar: `localhost:5000/chamado` -> ele será redirecionado ao login `localhost:5000` ou `localhost:5000/login`. Se ele tentar acessar a página `localhost:5000/home` -> ele será redirecionado ao login `localhost:5000` ou `localhost:5000/login`.

Mas a minha dúvida é fazer assim, se ele tentou acessar o `/chamado`, ele seja redirecionado para logar, e depois que logar, volte para `/chamado`. Ou se ele quiser acessar a `/home`, retorne para página de login, depois que ele logar, volte para página `home`.

Eu trabalho usando Node.js, e montei páginas em EJS e arquivos JS (JavaScript).
E no início criei um método que ele só direciona para página Home depois que loga, independente da parte que o usuário tentar logar.

No final do código, dentro do `then`, tem o `window.location`: `home`;
Que sempre depois de logar ele vai redirecionar para página ''home'', mas eu queria de alguma forma que ele retornasse para página que o usuário tentou acessar primeiro. Como por exemplo: `/chamado`.

**login.ejs**

```
function verifyIfUserIsLogged() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    const password = localStorage.getItem('password');

    if (user && password) { //verifica se tem login e password, e se tiver, direciona para rota X (no caso é a home)
        window.location = '/home';
    }
}

function setUserAtLocalStorage(e) {
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value; //pega o valor que está no user/input
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value; //pega o valor que está no password/input

    if(!user || !password ){ //! significa negação
        return alert("Dados inválidos!");
    }

    var body = {
        login: user,
        password: password
    };

    fetch('/login', { //faz uma requisição http
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', //o tipo de conteudo que vai ser aceito
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' //tipo de conteudo que está enviando
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(res => { //espera a requisição ser feita - promise
        localStorage.setItem('user', user); //salva no local storage
        localStorage.setItem('password', password);
        window.location = 'home'; //retorna a home
    });
}

verifyIfUserIsLogged(); //chama a função
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma lógica bem simples: salva o local atual do usuário, com `window.location.pathname` por exmeplo, e no retorno no *promise* redireciona para essa página:

```
// se o caminho for a raiz "/", definir como "/home", senão pega o caminho atual
var path = window.location.pathname == '/' ? '/home' : window.location.pathname;
fetch('/login', { //faz uma requisição http
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', //o tipo de conteudo que vai ser aceito
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' //tipo de conteudo que está enviando
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
            }).then(res => { //espera a requisição ser feita - promise
                localStorage.setItem('user', user); //salva no local storage
                localStorage.setItem('password', password);
                window.location = path; //retorna a home
            });
```

Se quiser ficar na página após autenticar, pode fazer um `reload` também

Comment: E quando você navega pra outra rota, "/teste" por exemplo, qual o valor na variável "path"?

Comment: Fiz isso também. E se eu troco aquela ''home'' no ''path'' para ''chamado'' por exemplo, aí ele começa a retornar sempre pra ''chamado'' depois que o usuário loga.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz dessa forma Ricardo Pontual, porém ele continua retornando para página home.
Pra você ter uma ideia, eu coloquei uma função na página chamado.ejs que ele valida se o usuário já logou no LocalStorage ou não.

```html
<script>
            const verifyIfUserIsLogged = () => {
            const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
            const password = localStorage.getItem('password');

            if (!user || !password) {
                window.location = '/';
            }
            
        }

        verifyIfUserIsLogged();

 </script>
```

Ele retorna para o login.ejs e depois de logar, ele vai para home.ejs
Abaixo como ficou o login.ejs:

```html
 <script>
    function verifyIfUserIsLogged() {
        const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
        const password = localStorage.getItem('password');

        if (user && password) { //verifica se tem login e password, e se tiver, direciona para rota X (no caso é a home)
            window.location = '/home';
        }
    }

    function setUserAtLocalStorage(e) {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value; //pega o valor que está no user/input
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value; //pega o valor que está no password/input
        
        if(!user || !password ){ //! significa negação
            return alert("Dados inválidos!");
        }

        var body = {
            login: user,
            password: password
        };
        
        var path = window.location.pathname == '/' ? '/home' : window.location.pathname;

        fetch('/login', { //faz uma requisição http
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', //o tipo de conteudo que vai ser aceito
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' //tipo de conteudo que está enviando
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        }).then(res => { //espera a requisição ser feita - promise
            localStorage.setItem('user', user); //salva no local storage
            localStorage.setItem('password', password);
            window.location = path; //retorna a home
        });
    }
    verifyIfUserIsLogged(); //chama a função
</script>
```